# Converting Dictionary in To Array

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have A dictionary .

```
{

background = "12.jpg";
denomination = 500;
logo = "2.jpg";
name = "Cafe Coffee Day";
product = "Voucher 500";
type = Voucher;

}
```

I want to converted in to Array

```
(
{


 background = "12.jpg";
    denomination = 500;
    logo = "2.jpg";
    name = "Cafe Coffee Day";
    product = "Voucher 500";
    type = Voucher;

}
)
```

I make loat of googled there is code for key or value. nOt getting full dictionary

Comment: So you want to wrap your dictionary with an array?

Comment: yes i want to wrap in array

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12001464/convert-dictionaries-into-one-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create an array with a single element; if `dictionary` is your `NSDictionary`, use

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObject:dictionary];
```

Answer (score 0):

You want an array with one element; that element is an array? Ok, if you really want:

```
NSArray *a = @[@{@"background":"12.jpg, @"denomination":@500, @"logo":@"2.jpg", ...}]
```

If you already have your dictionary, you can do:

```
NSArray *a = @[dictionary];
```